# Get Mobile no from real device

Tags: android

I want to get the mobile number of a sim which is inserted into the device. I know as pr the android SDK `TelephoneManger` is the class by which we can get it by `getLine1Number()` method. but it always returns null values.

**Queries:**

- Can i get mobile number from
  device?
- Is it a sim dependent or in some case
  also device dependent?
- Any other ways to get the mobile number from device?

Answer (score 4):

You are using correct and the only approach available to the common user (AFAIK). It is mainly SIM dependent (it is not obligatory to have ), and in some cases may be device dependent (getLine1Number() not correctly implemented).

To be more precise, IMSI uniquely identifies SIM. But MSISDN (the subscriber number) is not uniquely related to SIM, as it is possible to change MSISDN on the SIM. Network may use IMSI from SIM to find MSISDN in the HLR and establish the call.

So, MSISDN is not mandatory to be on the SIM.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/get-phone-number-in-android-sdk) and its comments.

Some SIM cards seems to cause getLine1Number() to return null... and no one has found a way to deal with this.

[More information here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443524/getline1number-return-null-but-not-always)

Comment: No one has found the way, because in that case number does not exist on the SIM.

Answer (score 1):

In that case you always save your phone no using SharedPreference  by using the method getLine1Number() method. when you install your application then your phone number is saven and when when new sim card is used then send SMS to ur registered number. you have to always check  after starting the application that your stored number is same with your new number.if same nothing will be happned ,if not same then ur app will send SMS.