# Phone SIM change notification

Tags: android

can we receive notification on phone SIM change.

Comment: possible duplicate of [event when sim is changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389512/event-when-sim-is-changed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think we can get the phone number.. so we can track the change of phone number on SIM change in background process.

```
 TelephonyManager tMgr=(TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

Comment: Good approach. But issue is that MSISDN (number) is not mandatory to be present on the SIM, so you cannot accurately track the change. So, it is better to monitor IMSI change. See more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967459/get-mobile-no-from-real-device/4967549#4967549