# Ensuring Device Phone number and App Phone number is same

Tags: android, ios, msisdn

**This can be move to general discussion**

I have an App that uses users Mobile Number. The mobile number is must to use the App and it is the main identifier of user. I have also the SMS verification. But according to the app policy it is must to have the same SIM in the device in which the app is using. Few other apps such as IMO, Viber or Whatsapp I can easily get the sms in other phone and input the verification key in other phone.

I tried `TelephonyManager` but in few device it returns null.

Is there any way (whether code base or paid solution) to ensure the same phone number using in the same device in which the app is installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement auto read of sms verification code in your app and no option for the user to enter the verification code. This way you can make sure that the user is logging in with the sim in that mobile where app is installed.

Answer (score 1):

This code will help you to get phone number

```
TelephonyManager tMgr=(TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

Please check following answers also

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4967549/4076507
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4967549/4076507

Comment: I have mentioned in my question that I have used that `TelephonyManager` already